How do i make a anvil inventory with nms
I am making a Minecraft plugin in 1.20.2 and want to get the users input with a anvil menu. I have searched and tried things but I can't figure out how to make a custom anvil inventory and open it.
This is what I have now:
import net.minecraft.core.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.network.chat.Component;
import net.minecraft.server.level.ServerPlayer;
import net.minecraft.world.inventory.AnvilMenu;
import net.minecraft.world.inventory.ContainerLevelAccess;
import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R2.entity.CraftPlayer;
import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R2.event.CraftEventFactory;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

    public void OpenAnvilMenu(Player player)
    {
        ServerPlayer serverPlayer = ((CraftPlayer) player).getHandle();

        BlockPos position = serverPlayer.blockPosition();

        AnvilMenu anvilMenu = new AnvilMenu(0, serverPlayer.getInventory(), ContainerLevelAccess.create(serverPlayer.level(), position));

        anvilMenu.setTitle(Component.translatable("Hello World"));

        CraftEventFactory.callInventoryOpenEvent(serverPlayer, anvilMenu);

        player.sendMessage("Opened anvil menu");
    }
}

It doesn't give a error in the console when i execute the code But it also does not open the menu.
the player does get the message "Opened anvil menu" when i execute the code.

In your code, you are calling CraftEventFactory.callInventoryOpenEvent(serverPlayer, anvilMenu) which call the InventoryOpenEvent event, but does not open the inventory by itself. The real method seems to be serverPlayer.initMenu(anvilMenu);.
But, there is an easier way: Keep using the spigot API.
Here is an example with PaperMC API's :
public void openAnvilMenu(Player player) {
    Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(player, InventoryType.ANVIL, Component.text("Hello World"));
    if(inv instanceof AnvilInventory anvilInv) { // should always be true
        anvilInv.setResult(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD)); // example code
        // here you can set all item of your inventory
    }
    player.openInventory(inv);
    player.sendMessage("Opened anvil menu");
}

Explaination and links:

Use createInventory(holder, type, name) to create the inventory
InventoryType is the type of inventory. Actually, there is only 3 that cannot be opened: CREATIVE, MERCHANT and CRAFTING.
The create inventory will be castable to AnvilInventory
Component.text("") is preferable than Component.translatable("") if you don't give a key that is translated. You can also use serializer to convert from old style to Component.


this will not work for my plication. i need to get the text that the player inputs in the anvil. this can not be done with the spigot api.

@Entropire why it would not be done ? Why you can't open the inventory with basic API then listen for NMS content?

How would you then get the name of the output item or the text in the input field of the anvil with nms?

You can just listen for event when the player get the renamed item on the right of the anvil. To know how to manage inventory, you can check my post here

You can't get the name of the out put item with the inventory click event of the spigot-api. the anvil container resets before you can get the name of the output item.

You have PrepareAnvilEvent that can be useful and should answer to your problem. You can also simply ask this in chat...

the PrepareAnvilEvent is not called when editing the items inside a custom anvil menu. I have tried this with your example code, my own code while using spigot-api and my own code while using nms in all cases it does not get called.

after a little more searching i found a solution.
instead of using:
CraftEventFactory.callInventoryOpenEvent(serverPlayer, anvilMenu);

you need to use:
serverPlayer.connection.send(new ClientboundOpenScreenPacket(anvilMenu.containerId, MenuType.ANVIL, anvilMenu.getTitle()));

now it will look like this:
import net.minecraft.core.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.network.chat.Component;
import net.minecraft.server.level.ServerPlayer;
import net.minecraft.world.inventory.AnvilMenu;
import net.minecraft.world.inventory.ContainerLevelAccess;
import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R2.entity.CraftPlayer;
import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R2.event.CraftEventFactory;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

    public void OpenAnvilMenu(Player player)
    {
        ServerPlayer serverPlayer = ((CraftPlayer) player).getHandle();

        BlockPos position = serverPlayer.blockPosition();

        AnvilMenu anvilMenu = new AnvilMenu(0, serverPlayer.getInventory(), ContainerLevelAccess.create(serverPlayer.level(), position));

        anvilMenu.setTitle(Component.translatable("Hello World"));

        serverPlayer.connection.send(new ClientboundOpenScreenPacket(anvilMenu.containerId, MenuType.ANVIL, anvilMenu.getTitle()));

        player.sendMessage("Opened anvil menu");
    }
}

